# How to show $S$ is a vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Fix vectors $a_1, . . . , a_m ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $S$ be the set of $x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_i · x = 0$ for all $i$.

I want to show that $S$ is a vector space.

A vector space $S$ is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication.
Consider 2 elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are elements of the set of $x$s.
Then $a_i(x_1 + x_2)$, by the distributive property of vector sums, $= a_i \cdot x_1 + a_i \cdot x_2 
=0 + 0
=0$.
So $a_i(x_1 + x_2) = 0$ and $S$ is closed under vector addition.

Let $c$ be a scalar.
$a_i(c(x_i))
=ca_ix_1$ by the commutative property of scalar sums.  S is closed under scalar multiplication.

Have I shown that $S$ is a vector space?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all you did is right, except a detail...

Usually, proving that a set is a subspace, students forget that the first step should be that set is nonempty (which indeed is equivalent to show that $0$ is element of the set). Most of the times this is obvious, but is something that is taken into account

Answer (score 0):

> A vector space $S$ is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Actually a vector space has to obey a whole bunch of axioms, which you will have encountered in your study. To show a **subset** $X$ of a **known vector space $V$** is a subspace, you apply the **subspace test**:

- Check $X \ne \emptyset$.
- Check $X$ is closed under vector addition.
- Check $X$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

The rest of your proof looks OK except:

- $a_i(x_1+x_2)$ should be a dot product
- $a_i(cx_i)$ should be the dot product $a_i\cdot(cx_1)$, and you're not really using "the commutative property of scalar sums" to drag that $c$ to the front of the expression: it's another property (of the dot product).
- You should show $S\ne\emptyset$. Hint: there's always at least one special vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a\cdot x = 0$

Answer (score 0):

In short; yes you have by your definition. Although a vector space is actually defined as a set with 2 operations satisfying 8 axioms see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space. Your proof only works because $R^n$ is known to be a vector space and you are actually proving that $S$ is a subspace of $R^n$ and so is also a vector space. You should also show that $S$ is non-empty for it to be a subspace. It is quite easy to show that $0$ is an element of $S$.